# Cumulocity smarREST response templates

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I am trying to set up the Cumulocity smartREST response templates to supply info  from the device object stored by an app. I am thinking it is not possible but I want to confirm because the documentation is brief and not clear.

I have successfully implemented MEASUREMENT POST templates previously but I am trying to do INVENTORY GET now. I have set some values in the device object and I can see them from tenant.cumulocity.com/inventory/managedObjects/id/. This could look like:

```
"custom_values": {
    "val1": "abcde",
    "val2": "fghij"
}
```

Now I go to the smartREST template web interface editor and create a template (eg t1) and set a message (eg m001) and set it to 'inventory' and 'get' and tick 'includes response'. I'm not sure if I need custom fields here. Then I create a response (eg r001) and I now have to fill in base pattern with a condition and some number of other patterns. I assume in one of those fields I have $.custom_values.val1 etc but all permutations I try result in 'no access to object' error from topic 's/e'.

My ideal result (from the above example) would be to publish to '/s/uc/t1' with 'm001' and receive 'r001,abcde' (ie custom_values.val1) and publish 'm002' and receive 'r001,fghij' (ie custom_values.val2).

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your MQTT user probably is just missing the rights to the object as it is created by the app (I guess the mqtt client is a device user).
The best approach here is to give this object you are creating from the app the fragment c8y_Global

```
{
    "name": "testObject3", 
    "c8y_Global": {},
    "custom_values": {
        "val1": "abcde",
        "val2": "fghij"
    }
}
```

This fragment will make this object available to all registered users. This is common practice for app meta data.