# Cumulocity SmartREST GET Template using MQTT

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I am trying to receive a response using a custom GET template implemented on the Cumulocity UI however I'm having some trouble. I have defined my message template like so:[Message Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doRXC.png) and my response template like so: [Response template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvSp8.png).

At the moment when I publish to topic `'s/uc/template1'` (where `template1` is my X-ID) with the payload of `'999, 12345'`(where `12345` is my External ID), no response is received and no error is found. The speeds are known to exist in the object because when I request a `GET` command to `{{url}}/inventory/managedObjects` this responds with:

```
            "speed": {
            "1": {
                "unit": "m/min",
                "value": 1
            },
            "2": {
                "unit": "m/min",
                "value": 1
            }
```

I've also followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434697/cumulocity-smarrest-response-templates) where @TyrManuZ suggests to add `c8y_Global: {}` to the application. I have done this through a `PUT` request to `{{url}}/inventory/managedObjects/{{deviceId}}` on Postman and can verify that `c8y_Global: {}` exists there.

Is there something I am doing wrong, and if so what is the correct way? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With your description I was able to get a response of the speed.1.value property. Keep in mind that the request and response template must reside in the same template collection and that the target object must have c8y_Global.

Comment: I'll give it a go thanks!